# Unable to ship ordered item when quantity is less than 1 in magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.4

I ordered an item with quantity is less than one. when creating shipment it shows the error "Shipment Document Validation Error(s): You can't create a shipment without products.
" .
Ordered item details - `https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31863006?key=80f59a34739a24c9bd03dde6874ac300`

when clicking on ship button item to ship details become blank [image: ship page]

Answer (score 0):

In your di.xml give following code
preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory" type="Module\Inventory\Rewrite\ShipmentItems"

Rewrite validateItem function.
Replace the if condition if (!$orderItem->isDummy(true)
&& (!isset($items[$orderItem->getId()]) || (int) $items[$orderItem->getId()] <= 0)

to if (!$orderItem->isDummy(true)
&& (!isset($items[$orderItem->getId()]) || $items[$orderItem->getId()] <= 0)
)
)

Comment: Yes, shipment has been made. But the status of the order stays on "processing" and not goes to completed. Did you also solved that?